# Grammar question, which statement would be correct?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

Good morning, I am writing an essay on file compression and I have written this sentence and I am not sure whether the first or second version would be correct.

The statement is:

> "Lossless compression is essential as files which require all data to be present, such as a financial report or a database[...]"

Would "*such as a financial report or database*" be grammatically correct, or would "*such as a financial report or **a** database*" be correct?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be correct, but their meaning is slightly different.

> such as a financial report or database

implies that the *database* needs to be financial, just as the report is. With

> such as a financial report or a database

you're effectively limiting the adjective *financial* to the noun *report*.

Comment: Aaah right, I understand, thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of it before! I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Samuelf80 you're welcome. You can [*accept*](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your question.